# Cancel buttons Zenity

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, notification, zenity

So, I have this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
#InputBox1Test

title=$(zenity --entry --text 'Type what you want your Notification Title to Say!' --title 'Notification')
text=$(zenity --entry --text 'Type what you want your Notification body to Say!' --title 'Notification')
DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send "$title" "$text"
```

This script opens a zenity window, and walks you through generating a notification.  I want to make it exit when you press cancel.  How do I do that?

Comment: Below each line add a new line `echo "$?"` and then test what zenity returns for each button plus escape key. Then later put in test of values you wish to trap and act upon.

Comment: it comes out for cancel to "1" and okay "0"  how do I make the if statement

Comment: You should really test `Escape` key and `Ctrl` + `F4` key too but I'll write an answer for `1` and `0`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks alot!  this made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that return value is `1` for "cancel" and `0` for "ok" you will want to use:

```
#!/bin/sh
#InputBox1Test

title=$(zenity --entry --text 'Type what you want your Notification Title to Say!' --title 'Notification')
[[ "$?" != "0" ]] && exit 1
text=$(zenity --entry --text 'Type what you want your Notification body to Say!' --title 'Notification')
[[ "$?" != "0" ]] && exit 1
DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send "$title" "$text"
```

You can make a longer traditional check like this:

```
if [[ "$?" != "0" ]] ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

however I like the shortcut of:

```
[[ "$?" != "0" ]] && exit 1
```

No matter which method you choose the importance is consistency with your programming style so those that follow in your footsteps and maintain your code can think inside your head.